# ArtemisMQ - does work in cluster based on peer to peer?

Tags: messaging, activemq-artemis

I need to write a quick review about ArtemisMQ. One point consider the architecture of ArtemisMQ in cluster. According documentation (or rather how i understand this) nodes work independently - each node can be discovered and then the create some core bridge connections between each other. It's seems to be P2P. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that could be said here, but in short your description looks accurate to me (an Artemis developer).

One other thing...It's not called "ArtemisMQ," but rather simply "Artemis."